# Jquery-mobile conflicts with google analatics

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, google-analytics

when I include ga.js and jquery mobile the page disappears 
Here is the html:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.7.1.js" ></script> 
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" ></script> 
    </head>
     <body>
        <p>some text</p>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
        document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("****");
        pageTracker._initData();
        pageTracker._trackPageview();
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I tested it on chrome on windows 7 and also on safari on ipad.

Comment: Do not include `document.write` in pages that get loaded in with ajax. This has very little to do with JQM. You'll have to find another way to track your page views since technically only one pageview is happening regardless of how many different *"pages"* are being navigated through after the first.

Comment: and u must add jQM's css. only then will the page have any mobile markup

Comment: This doesn't seem like current analytics snippet. Create a new one!